# Node js crypto sign returns empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

I am wanting to sign a string with a private key using crypto.

The sign method returns an empty string, I was hoping to get a signiture.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var message = "This is a string I want to ensure is not tampered with.";

var diffieHellman = crypto.createDiffieHellman(1024);
var publicKey = diffieHellman.generateKeys("base64");
var privateKey = diffieHellman.getPrivateKey("base64");

var signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
signer.write(message, "ascii", function()
{
    var signature = signer.sign(privateKey, 'base64');

    console.log(publicKey);
    console.log(privateKey);
    console.log(signature);// Empty string ?
});
```

The public key and private key are generated fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that DH != RSA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with crypto, confirmed here :

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6963

To solve, use a bit length of 512 and signer.

Here is working code

```
var keypair = require('keypair');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var dataA = "This is a string I do not want to be tampered with";
var dataB = "This is a string I do want to be tampered with";

var pair = keypair({bits:256});
console.log("Private   :"+pair['private']);
console.log(" Public   :"+pair['public']);

var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.write(dataA);
var signiture = sign.sign(pair['private'],'base64');

console.log("Signiture :"+signiture);
```

Answer (score 1):

The key needed for `sign(...)` is a `PEM` encoded RSA key but the key generated by `createDiffieHellman` is not that as far as I know. I think your best bet would be to generate a PEM key with `OpenSSL`.

Comment: Although both systems rely on modular exponentiation, DH key pairs are not the same as RSA private keys. If they would work, they would have very serious security issues. The type of error returned by the lib (none) is a bit worry-some though. IMHO scripting languages with dynamic typing are not very well suited to security related applications.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Do you know how I would go about doing this with node.js crypto? Just some pointers to which methods I should use. Thanks.

Comment: @bluelightzero RSA key pair generation does not seem to be included with NodeJS. The reason is probably that it would take a very long time to create RSA key pairs using NodeJS - RSA key pair gen is notoriously slow. Random number generation may be an issue as well.